# Detect whether a cache line is reused due to spatial or temporal locality

Tags: valgrind, cpu-cache, cachegrind, cache-locality

Is there a practical tool to detect whether a cache line is reused (a cache miss is avoided) due to either **spatial** or **temporal** locality?

I could not find a related discussion in [cachegrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html).
I was able to find only [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11758525_68) and [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4770561) papers but not the tools introduced in them.